# Update subsection of mapped knockout object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I know this question sounds familiar, but I have read so many of the similar questions and have not been able to find my specific situation.

I have a javascript object called gds (GlobalDataStructure). As its name suggests, this object contains all the information I need for all the web pages of my project and is stored in localStorage (hence why I am not just updating view model and need to map in the first place). It contains all sorts of feeds that are read via AJAX.

I use a constructor function to create gds. To massively simplify this structure and hopefully make this question simple, let's say gds was

```
function gdStructure(){
    this.lastUpdate = new Date(2010,1,1);
    this.family = new Object();
    this.series = new Object();
    this.product = new Object();
}
```

so I have

```
gds= new gdStructure();
```

then once i have populated the js array with data from initial feeds, I do the following.

```
    viewmodel = ko.mapping.fromJS(gds);
    ko.mapping.fromJS(gds,viewmodel);
```

The view model is then bound to each page with

```
ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
```

So this all works no problem. This issue arises when I, for example, get a new family feed and I want to update that object. I can do the following

```
gds.family=feed;
ko.mapping.fromJS(gds,viewmodel);
```

And all would work fine, but that is mapping a MASSIVE JS object every time. This is extremely slow so I need to find a way where I can update just the feed that has changed. ideally something like..

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(gds.family, viewmodel.family);
```

But this appears not to work. Also because it is an OBJECT I can't just do.

```
viewmodel.family(gds.family)
```

Can anybody help me? I am sure this must be so simple.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missunderstood how the lib works, this part looks very strange

```
viewmodel = ko.mapping.fromJS(gds);
ko.mapping.fromJS(gds,viewmodel);
```

Your using the definition as data?

Anyway, I use ko.mapping like this (A bit simplified but i think you get the point)

http://jsfiddle.net/QtyGd/1/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Surely the 
viewmodel = ko.mapping.fromJS(gds)
Creates the viewmodel data structure and sets all the keys to be ko.observables and Arrays to be Knockout Arrays. That is the way I understood it to work??
Then
the ko.mapping.fromJS(gds,Viewmodel) updates the view model with the latest data in gds.
Is that not correct! Otherwise how can you define the viewmodel as the   Array stuctures vary massively and are huge, hence the purpose of mapping in the first place?

Comment: gds and viewmodel are the same object in your code, were does the actual data come into picture? See my fiddle how to do it. There is a model and data

Comment: The data get read into a feed and stored in GDS. That is then mapped to Viewmodel. GDS cannot be a knockout viewmodel as it needs to be sorted in localStorage. If I stored the viewmodel I would be storing functions not data. I know it can be converted back to JS before storing, but since this data is updated on the fly from feeds, I dont want to have to do that with the entire viewmodel all the time.

Comment: Each of the feeds has many variables and arrays in a pretty complex structure. hence using the mapping plugin.

Comment: You only need to specific declare the members that you want to have as observable. Look at this fiddle, i added another complex object to the data without adding a member for it on the VM, its automatic transferred to the view model. http://jsfiddle.net/QtyGd/2/